# SQL Задача ПОМОЩЬ в решении

Tags: sql, select

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Как получить таблицу, в которой отражено распределение суммы выдач и кол-ва выдач по возрастным группам (<25 лет, 25-35, 36-45, 46-55, 56+) (возраст на момент открытия кредита)?
Как задать этот временной интервал от даты выдачи кредита и соотнести с днём рождения из 1 таблицы ?

Comment: А какой именно у вас sql и поддерживает ли он оконные функции ? Если да - то используйте `sum() over()`. Если нет - то ваше решение нормальное. Можно вынести получение суммы в join, в случае если вдруг оптимизатор в вашей БД не понимает что получение суммы можно выполнить один раз (большинство оптимизаторов это отлично сами поймут)

Comment: Postgare SQL у меня. 
То есть SQL  нормально сам посчитает умножение числа на % ?
Я единственное добавил еще / 100 : вот 
SELECT (amount * (rate / 100)) / (select sum(amount) FROM таблица) from таблица.

Такое решение верное ???

Comment: Я не понял что такое "умножение на процент". Если процент это просто число, выраженное в процентах, то да, надо просто дополнительно поделить на 100. А раз постгрес, то он отлично умеет оконные функции и получать сумму отдельным подзапросом не надо. `SELECT (amount * rate / 100) / sum(amount) over() from таблица`

Comment: только по моему это не средневзвешенная ставка получается. Средне взвешенная же должна быть одним числом по таблице `select sum(rate * amount) / sum(amount) from таблица`

Comment: Да! Только вам хотел написать ! что на сумму строк и процентов посчитать sum(rate * amount).  и тут же получается надо раздлить на 100. Раз rate выражены в процентах ?

Comment: не надо делить на 100 если результат хотите получить в тех же процентах

Comment: Я просто не представляю что на приведенном экране делает символ процент после чисел. В базе же просто число лежит, я специального типа данных для процентов не знаю. А раз это просто число то и работаем с ним по правилам математики

Comment: Спасибо благодарю!помогли

Comment: SELECT sum(amount),
       count(amount),
        CASE
        WHEN open_date – birthdate > 0 AND open_date – birthdate < 25 THEN '<25 лет',
        WHEN open_date – birthdate >= 25 AND open_date – birthdate <= 35  THEN '25-35 лет'
        WHEN open_date – birthdate >= 36 AND open_date – birthdate <= 45  THEN '36-45 лет'
        WHEN open_date – birthdate >= 46 AND open_date – birthdate <= 55  THEN '46-55 лет'
        ELSE '56+' end       
FROM T2
LEFT JOIN T3 ON T2.id_contract = T3.id_contract
LEFT JOIN T1 ON T3.id_client = T1.id_client 
У меня вышло такое решение ?

Comment: вычитание дат дает interval, а не года. думаю надо из него extract делать. https://postgrespro.ru/docs/postgrespro/10/functions-datetime И собственно что вы спрашиваете верно или нет, любой запрос надо наживую проверять, вдруг там какие нибудь синтаксические ошибки не заметные на глаз